# close each div of the same class separate using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

i have a piece of jquery which fades in several divs of the same class, kind of like news feeds. for example the `<div class="dashboard_notification">` is faded in several times one after the other with a delay using this code:

```
<script>
$('.dashboard_notification').hide(); // this or use css to hide the div
$(document).ready(function(){
    var time = 1000;
    $('.dashboard_notification').each(function() {
        $(this).delay(time).fadeIn(1000);
        time += 1000;
    });
});
</script>
```

now what i am trying to do is isolate each one of these (pref without having to change the div class to something like `"dashboard_notification1/2/3/4"`) so that the user can click to close each news feed separately to the others using the special close button div i have assigned `"dashboard_notification_close"`

can someone show me how i could do this thanks, heres the code im using to close the div at the moment but this just closes all of the news feeds as they all share the same div class="dashboard_notification"

```
<script>
$('.dashboard_notification_close').click(function(e) { //button click class name is myDiv 
  e.stopPropagation(); 
 }) 

 $(function(){ 
  $('.dashboard_notification_close').click(function(){   
  $('.dashboard_notification').delay(100).fadeOut(500);

 }); 

}); 
</script>
```

Comment: post relevant HTML markup so we can see relation between close button and the div. Maybe using `$(this).closest('.dashboard_notification')` but just I'm just guessing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming markup looks like this:

```
<div class="dashboard_notification">
...
    <div class="dashboard_notification_close"></div>
...
</div>
```

You can use `this` to refer to the clicked button and `closest` to reach its outer `div`:

```
$('.dashboard_notification_close').click(function(){   
    $(this).closest('.dashboard_notification').delay(100).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your click function, switch `$('.dashboard_notification')` to `$(this)`, and it will only trigger on the element that was clicked, not all that match the selector query.

Comment: but `this` would be `'.dashboard_notification_close'` not relative `'.dashboard_notification'`

Comment: the problem i have is if the user clicks on 'dashboard_notification' this is suppose to hyperlink them to a url of that news feed, so instead of having them click dashboard_notification to close it, i want to use 'dashboard_notificaiton_close' to trigger the close of that individual 'dashboard_notification'